# To convert integer to hex in perl

Tags: perl

I have an integer say 6677889.I want to use this value as hex that is 0x66778899 in my perl script.How to use that?Using sprintf,gives the direct hex value of that.I don't want that to happen.How to go abt it ? Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 7):

You mean something other than this?

```
% perl -e "print hex 6677889"
107444361
```